# Is it possible to make table with different columns for different rows?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

I am using `bootstrap4` and I want to make a table where `first` row have `3` columns, another two rows with `4` columns. i.e. to look like this

[image]

My current table

```html
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">1П</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%">2П</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Прод.</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: start with the highest number of columns and then use colspan attribute to merge the columns to get a lower number where needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code renders an incomplete table, so some browsers might try to make it complete producing an unexpected result. But you can simply add another cell in the first row, leave it empty and make its border invisible:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr:first-of-type>td:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">1П</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%">2П</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Прод.</td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with built-in class.

remove the border class `table-bordered` on `table`, then add `border`class to `td`s

```html
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table m-5 w-50"><!-- demo purpose , use of w-50 and m-5 classes is optional-->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" class="border">1П</td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%" class="border">2П</td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="25%" class="border">Прод.</td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
      <td width="25%" class="border"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```